# Performing an action on a form that has been dynamically created

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am a beginner in programming and am stuck in a problem. I have cloned a form and now I want to empty it except the last child(element). I have tried the following but that doesn't work.

```
var originalform = $('form.defaultForm').last();  //this gets the form end.

var form_template = $('form.defaultForm').first(); //this gets the form that is then cloned

var newform = form_template.clone();  //this clones the form

newform.insertAfter(originalform);   //inserts the form after the original form

newform.addClass("mynewform");  //add class to new form

$('form.mynewform:not(:last)').empty();  //empty everything in the new form except the last child(element) this doesn't work
```

Comment: `form.mynewform:not(:last)` selects all forms with that class, that are not the last child of _their_ parent. You want `form.mynewform :not(:last)` to select all _children_ of the form, that are not _its_ last child. (Well, that would actually require `>` instead of the space, otherwise it selects all _descendants_ that are not the last child of _their_ respective parent. Which one exactly you need, depends on your form structure.)

Comment: $('form.mynewform>:not(:last)').empty();  you mean this should work?

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: provide html .. or create snippet/[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: First and foremost I mean, if you want to know, then either try it - or give us enough information to be able to reproduce the situation in the first place - see [mcve]. We don't know what your form looks like, so we can't possibly know whether that will select what you want or not.

Comment: my form contains select and input elements only nothing else. it's just a simple form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if I clearly understood you problem and what do you need to achive, but here is something.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(e){
  var $el = $('#to-clone').clone();
  $el.find("input:not(:last-child)").remove();
  $el.appendTo('#destination');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="to-clone" style="border:1px solid;">
<input type="text" value="1"/>
<input type="text" value="2"/>
<input type="text" value="3"/>
<input type="text" value="4"/>
</form>
<button>clone</button>
<div id="destination" style="padding:10px;background:red;">
fff
</div>
```

Comment: That was what I wanted. But you have specified input only. How can I remove everything except the last element?

Comment: replace input with * (star)